# Scrivener capitalization issues

Tags: novel, formatting, poetry, scrivener

I have a Scrivener formatting question. Using Scrivener (on Mac), I'm trying to put a poem into a page of a novel. Scrivener keeps capitalizing the first word of the next line even though the previous line has no period.

This is what I want:

**Line in a page of the novel.



Poem Line one

poem line 2.

Poem line 3,

poem line 4.**

This is what I get:

**Line in a page of the novel.



Poem line one

Poem line 2.

Poem line 3,

poem line 4.**

I'm a novice at Scrivener so I must be missing something obvious about how to change formatting rules. If someone could just point me in the direction of a way to change Scrivener formatting, you'd be my hero for at least the rest of the day.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Preferences > Corrections, and uncheck this:

[image]

Sentences will no longer automatically capitalize the first letter.